# Only showing Style for sometime then remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

I am working on a project where I need to show css style I add, then show for 2 seconds then revert back to normal. You can see my add the border, then I want to be able to remove it after say 2seconds. But I dont want it to loop through the rest of the code yet! I tried the set timeout, but couldn't get it to work.

```
function showComputersMoves() {
    document.getElementById('computersMove').style.display = "block";

    console.log(computersHand[intervalCount]);

    if (computersHand[intervalCount] == "Rock") {
        console.log("Yep, i work");
        document.getElementById("computerRock").style.border = "solid 2px red";
        setTimeout(2000);
        document.getElementById("computerRock").style.border = "";

    }
    else if (computersHand[intervalCount] == "Paper") {
        console.log("Yep, i work");
        document.getElementById("computerPaper").style.border = "solid 2px red";
        intervalCount++;
    }
    else if (computersHand[intervalCount] == "Scissors") {
        console.log("Yep, i work");
        document.getElementById("computerScissors").style.border = "solid 2px red";
        intervalCount++;
    }
    if(computersHand.length == intervalCount){
        clearInterval();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is invalid syntax for `setTimeout`. You need to declare a function to use after the timeout. Here's how you'd fix that first `if` statement:

```
if (computersHand[intervalCount] == "Rock") {
    console.log("Yep, i work");
    document.getElementById("computerRock").style.border = "solid 2px red";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("computerRock").style.border = "";
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: So I had this but it keeps excuting other code. So like eventually i hide the  id "computersMove" so it doesn't even showthis code. so my idea/hoping with the set time I could just pasue the code execution, which sounds like isn't possible